# RESTful API across multiple users

Tags: python, xml, linux, rest

I am somewhat new to RESTful APIs.

I'm trying to implement a python system that will control various tasks across multiple computers, with one computer acting as the controller.
I would like all these tasks to be divided amongst multiple users (ex. task foo runs as user foo, and task bar runs as user bar) while handling all requests with a central system. The central system should also act as a simple web server and be able to server basic pages for status purposes.

It it possible to have each user register a "page" with a central server for the API and have the server pass all requests to the programs (probably written in Python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just need the clients to POST their notifications URL to the server, so that the server can then POST them back with the requests. These are called [Webhooks](http://wiki.webhooks.org/w/page/13385124/FrontPage) by some people.

Also see [RESTful Webhooks](http://wiki.webhooks.org/w/page/13385128/RESTful-WebHooks).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Keep in mind that being RESTful is merely a way to organize your web application's URL's in a standard way.  You can build your web application to do whatever you want.